# Is this impossible given intra/contra/covariance?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

What I want to achieve is the following.

I have an interface like

```
interface ISomething<T>
{
   void Input(T item);

   IEnumerable<T> Outputs();
}
```

and a hierarchy like

```
interface IFoo { }
interface IBar : IFoo { }
interface IBaz : IFoo { }
```

I want to be able to refer to an `ISomething<IBaz>` and `ISomething<IBar>` by `ISomething<IFoo>` so that I can write methods like

```
void ProcessFoos(ISomething<IFoo> somethings)
{
    foreach (var something in somethings)
    {
       var outputs = something.Outputs();
       // do something with outputs
    }
}
```

where `somethings` could be combinations of `ISomething<IBar>`s and `ISomething<IBaz>`s.

Is this not possible given the language constraints?

If not, how can I redesign this as such?

**EDIT:** Here's a better example of what I'm talking about

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IBar<IX> x = new Bar<Y>() { };
        // ^^^ Cannot implicitly convert type 'Bar<Y>' to 'IBar<IX>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    }
}

public interface IBar<T> where T : IX
{
    void In(T item);

    T Out { get; }
}

public class Bar<T> : IBar<T> where T : IX
{
    public void In(T item) { }

    public T Out { get { return default(T); } }
}

public interface IX { }

public class Y : IX { }
```

Comment: I’ve tried to do this without success as well, but it does work if you declare the interface as `in`, then implement it explicitly in your code classes.

Comment: @theMayer see my Edit

Comment: Your edit is a totally new question.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating `somethings` as an `IEnumerable`, which it is not. If you want to iterate through the outputs, call it like this.

```
void ProcessFoos(ISomething<IFoo> something)
{
  foreach (var output in something.Outputs())
  {
    if(output is IBar)
    {
      // do something IBar related
    }
    else if(output is IBaz)
    {
      // do something IBaz related
    }
  }
}
```

If `somethings` was supposed to be an `IEnumerable`, change the signature of `ProcessFoos` like this:

```
void ProcessFoos(IEnumerable<ISomething<IFoo>> somethings)
{
  foreach (var something in somethings)
  {
    var outputs = something.Outputs();
    var barOutputs = outputs.OfType<IBar>();
    var bazOutputs = outputs.OfType<IBaz>();

    // do something with outputs
  }
}
```

This works for me.

If this doesn't work for you, please provide the error(s) you see and/or clarify what you are trying but unable to achieve.

Comment: Kristoffer, See my Edit